# Python: Make a if statement to do something when a certain error is raised?

Tags: python

I am making a connect4 game on python, and when a column is full, this error is raised when a player puts a piece in the full column. How do I make a if statement to say that if this error is raised, print("Make a valid move?")

```
class ConnectFourGameOverError(Exception):
    '''Raised whenever an attempt is made to make a move after the game is
    already over'''
    pass
```

Comment: Exceptions are handled in try-except-blocks in Python; why are you writing a game when you don't know the language syntax?

Comment: @ClassStacker: To learn the language syntax ... ? Silly question, really, making a connect4 game is obviously an exercise.

Comment: @cha0site And working on an exercise means you will neither get an introduction to the required Python concepts, nor do you read the python.org documentation, nor will you search for _python exception_ on the web? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use `try/except`

```
try:
    # your code here
except YourError:
    # do something
```

What this does is executes a piece of code, and 'catches' the given exception, if it occurs. For example, inspect this code:

```
try:
    num = raw_input('Enter an number: ')  # user enters something
    num = int(num)  # Python tries to convert it to an integer
except ValueError:  # if the input was invalid
    print 'You didn\'t enter an valid number'
```